# How do I initialize a two-dimensional List statically?

Tags: java, list, initialization, arraylist, multidimensional-array

How can I initialize a multidimensional List statically?

This works:

```
List<List<Integer>> list = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
```

But I'd like to init the list with some static lists like: (1,2,3), (4,5,6) and (7,8,9)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This is an old answer, but things have changed a bit. For java 9+ this can be done using the `List.of()` method which returns an immutable List which is a subclass of `AbstractImmutableList`.

```
import java.util.List;

List<List<Integer>> list = List.of(
                               List.of(1, 2, 3),
                               List.of(4, 5, 6),
                               List.of(7, 8, 9)
                           );
```

For older version of java or if one needs a mutable `List` the old answer still works:

### 2011 answer

If you create a helper method, the code looks a bit nicer. For example

```
public class Collections {
    public static <T> List<T> asList(T ... items) {
        List<T> list = new ArrayList<T>();
        for (T item : items) {
            list.add(item);
        }

        return list;
    }
}
```

and then you can do (with a static import)

```
List<List<Integer>> list = asList(
                             asList(1,2,3),
                             asList(4,5,6),
                             asList(7,8,9),
                           );
```

**Why I don't use Arrays.asList()**

> Arrays.asList() returns a class of type java.util.Arrays.ArrayList (it's an inner class of Arrays). The problem I've found is that it's VERY easy to think that one is using a java.lang.ArrayList, but their implementation are **very, very** different.

The comment above is also old, for java 9+ use `List.of(E...elem)`.

Comment: Arrays.asList() does the function listed above.

Comment: Why do you need to create a helper method when java.util.Arrays.asList does this?  See x4u's answer.

Comment: @JustinKSU & @ditkin: it's not 100% identical, please check the comment I levt on x4u answer.

Comment: @Augusto Can you please add your concerns about the Arrays.asList to this answer.  You mentioned headaches, can you elaborate on that.  It would make this answer extremely useful and remove any doubt that people might have about re-inventing a solution that exists in the java library.

Comment: If I use the code above I get this warning: "Type safety : A generic array of List<Integer> is created for a varargs parameter"

Comment: I agree with Augusto, the `List` objects you get from `Arrays.asList()` are not `ArrayList` objects but are merely wrappers around the array that was given to `asList()`. These objects are less usefull in many circumstances, i.e. they don't allow insertion of further elements.

Comment: @Cody that's because the method asList returns a non-parameterized list, but the method signature says that it should be parameterized. Unfortunately this happens with all the methods that transform an array to a collection.

Comment: Well, *interfaces are very, very different* is not really true. Both classes implement that same interfaces, they just behave differently at runtime, which is even worse.

Comment: @cody: You can get it type safe. I dared to edit it directly into Augustos answer.

Comment: In 2016 it's also nice. Btw, it can be simplifed to: `public static <T> List<T> asList(T... items) {
        return new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(items));
    }`

Comment: Thanks @Augusto. And Arrays.asList "Returns a fixed-size list backed by the specified array. (Changes to the returned list "write through" to the array.) This method acts as bridge between array-based and collection-based APIs, in combination with Collection.toArray(). The returned list is serializable and implements RandomAccess.
This method also provides a convenient way to create a fixed-size list initialized to contain several elements." -- from JDK API doc
Thus, the size of the created list cannot be expanded or shrunk, which means it doesn't work in many case.

Comment: Great auxiliary method. It can be simplified like this:
`public static <T> List<T> asList(T ... items) {
    List<T> list = new ArrayList<>();
    Collections.addAll(list, items);

    return list;
  }`

Answer (score 10):

You can do it this way:

```
import static java.util.Arrays.*;
```

...

```
List<List<Integer>> list = asList(
    asList( 1, 2, 3 ),
    asList( 4, 5, 6 ),
    asList( 6, 7, 8 ) );
```

Comment: I avoid using Arrays.asList() as it returns an "java.util.Arrays.ArrayList", not a java.util.ArrayList . This little fact caused me many headaches, that's why I use my own "asList()"

Comment: Yes you are right. `Arrays.asList()` is only usefull if you need a read only List and the `List` objects you get from it are not even really well suited for that. But it's the shortest way to statically initialize a `List` object that Java has to offer out of the box and for many purposes it works quite well.

Comment: You are right, but in my experience it's better to avoid it. I've seen a few very good developers spending hours trying to find bugs related to this. The fact that the inner class is called ArrayList too is a big enough source of confusion for me, so I prefer to leave it aside.

Comment: That's true and I agree that it was a very unfortunate name choice on the side of those who implemented this.

Answer (score 8):

You can do so by adding a static block in your code.

```
private static List<List<Integer>> list = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
static {
  List<Integer> innerList = new ArrayList<Integer>(3);
  innerList.add(1);
  innerList.add(2);
  innerList.add(3);
  list.add(innerList);
  //repeat
}
```

Comment: You can as well use list.add(Arrays.asList(1,2,3) ) to generate inner elements in single line of code.