# Initialize List<List<Integer>> in Java

Tags: java

How can I initialize `List<List<Integer>>` in Java?

I know `List` is an interface and I can use `ArrayList` or `LinkedList` to implement `List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>()`, but when I initialize `List<List<Integer>> list = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();` I get error incompatible types:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> cannot be converted to List<List<Integer>>.
```

So how can I proceed?

Comment: I would like to call what you need a `declaration` rather than an `initailization`. See this linke: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6232986/how-do-i-initialize-a-two-dimensional-list-statically

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Use

```
List<List<Integer>> list = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
```

or since Java 1.7

```
List<List<Integer>> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: thanks God, there is no explanation behind this , so we can learn?

Comment: The question is how to proceed so I'll let the OP search for terms like "invariance" and "diamond operator" :)

Comment: A little bit of explanation of how and why this works can help a lot of people.

Answer (score 8):

You can define it as `List<List<Integer>> list = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();`.

Then while defining the inner `List` you can take care of initialising it as `ArrayList<Integer>`.

Answer (score 2):

You can define it as `List<List<Integer>> list = new LinkedList();`

Answer (score 1):

You can initialize this as

```
List<ArrayList<Integer>> list = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
```

Note that the inner List has to be an implementation of the List interface, e.g., ArrayList.
Since List is an interface, one can't have objects of the type List itself.

Comment: Thanks Suraj, I was fixing the html for angle brackets while you edited the comment

Comment: The OP wanted to initialize List<List<Integer>>, not List<ArrayList<Integer>>.